# Unable to find xpath using position(), last(),[1] indexing([1]--eg.) following:siblings, child, parent nothing is working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to find out the XPATH. I am getting 30 matches for an element.

I tried using last(), position(), indexing[], child, parent, following:siblings, preceding:siblings, absolute XPATH is also not working, how to achieve this.

Comment: What have you tried so far as code, show the code and the html and not with a screenshot.

Comment: //span[@class='cursor']//*[local-name()='svg'][@class='excel-document'][1]

Comment: //span[@class='cursor']//*[local-name()='svg'][@class='excel-document']/following::sibling::*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but I've only recently discovered myself the solution to this type of problem.  Surround the main xpath with parenthesis, place the subscript AFTER.

Assuming that your basic xpath is correct, the following should isolate element 1:

```
(//span[@class='cursor']//*[local-name()='svg'][@class='excel-document'])[1]
```

Comment: Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

**Absolute xpath:**

```
html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/h4[1]/b
```

**Relative xpath:**

```
//*[@class='featured-box']//*[text()='Testing']
```

Might be the syntax you are using is wrong

Comment: Thanks, It was answered by Bill